# What size chunks should I copy files in?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

Our .NET app copies large files, and needs to give the user feedback; so rather than use `File.Copy` we read a chunk of one file and write it to the other, and display the progress after each chunk.  Nothing out of the ordinary.  But what's the right size of chunk to use, to give the fastest file copy, assuming the time to display the progress is negligible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using win32 function [CopyFileTransacted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363853%28VS.85%29.aspx) (Vista Only) or [CopyFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363852%28VS.85%29.aspx) (Windows 2000 and higher). These are provided by Windows and are optimized for speed.

I would recommend you to test your custom C# implementation performance and compare it to native File.Copy performance. If the performance is comparable (i.e. same order of magnitude) than go with your custom C# implementation. Otherwise it's better to use CopyFileTransacted or CopyFileEx function.

P.s. from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363853%28VS.85%29.aspx):

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true)]
internal static extern bool CopyFileTransacted([In] string lpExistingFileName, [In] string lpNewFileName, [In] IntPtr lpProgressRoutine, [In] IntPtr lpData, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] ref bool pbCancel, [In] CopyFileFlags dwCopyFlags, [In] KtmTransactionHandle hTransaction);
```

Comment: is CopyFileTransacted available on XP?

Comment: No CopyFileTransacted is supported starting from Windows Vista. But CopyFileEx is supported on XP and it also provides progress information. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

A very large buffer will give you the best transfer speed but a coarse feedback. So it's a trade-off and it also depends very much on the hardware.

I did something like this a while back and settled on a 64k buffer, but you might want to experiment a little.

And whatever you pick, make sure it's a multiple of 512 (1 sector)

Answer (score 0):

Even when using larger chunks you can easily estimate the progress to give the user "faked" feedback.
Depending on the application why don't you let the user set the size? Give the user option if he wants it :)

Comment: The user does *not* want options!

Comment: "Mother, just change the file transfer buffer size if it's copying too slowly..."

Comment: The best way to provide the user with "options" is the UI design where you have a "More Info" or "Show Details" button that shows more details, when that's enabled the buffer size can be shrunk to be smaller as to provide more frequent user feedback, but when collapsed it could be more granular.